# How to define type conversion to string for a custom type

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

Can I define how a conversion to string, using `String()` would be applied to my custom type `myint`? And how to do so?

I was expecting to define the method `String()` to be enough as it is used by `fmt.Println()` but apparently not by `string()`. This is purely a theoretical question as I am learning Go and was surprised by this behavior.

Here is an example showing the behavior:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myint int

func (m myint) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", m)
}

func main() {
    var val myint = 42
    mystr := "Testing: " + string(val)
    fmt.Println(mystr, val)
}
```

Which outputs:

> Testing: * 42

But I was expecting:

> Testing: 42 42

Comment: "I was expecting [...]". What part of the language spec or the Tour of Go made you expect this?

Comment: @Volker it was an intuition because I thought `string()` would use the same mechanism as `fmt.Println()`, the tour made me think that the stringer is a bigger deal than what it actually is... Also Python have this behavior.

Comment: The construct `string(x)` is not a function call but a type conversion because `string` is not a function but a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I define how a conversion to string, using `string()` would be applied to my custom type `myint`? And how to do so?

No, you can't "override" conversion behavior. It's recorded in [Spec: Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), and that's the end of it. The `String()` method works for the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package because the `fmt` package is written to explicitly check for the presence of the `String() string` method. Conversions don't do that.

If you need custom conversion behavior, don't use conversion, but implement your logic in methods (or functions), and call those methods (or functions).

So in your example you would write:

```
mystr := "Testing: " + val.String()
```

And you would get your expected output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iBt8icsB88w)):

```
Testing: 42 42
```

Comment: Technically `fmt` looks for the [`Stringer` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer).